# How do you use data in a text field?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the data in the text field to transfer to a popup, but when I trigger the popup, it is always blank, no matter what is in the box.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Popup</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="popup()">Click for popup</button>
  <input type="text" name=popupMess><br>
 </body>
 <script>
  function popup() {
     window.confirm(name.popupMess);
  }
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, you forgive the "" in name, would be name= "popupMess"

Comment: should move the <script> in the body and replace `name.popupMess` with `document.querySelector("input[name='popupMess']").value`

Comment: Try window.confirm(document.getElementsByName("popupMess")[0].value);

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `"`  in `name="popupMess"`.

```
function popup () {
    var text = document.querySelector("input[name='popupMess']").value;

    window.confirm(text);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Popup</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="popup()">Click for popup</button>
  <input id="popupMess" type="text"><br>
 </body>
 <script>
  function popup() {
    alert(document.getElementById('popupMess').value);
  }
 </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is my jsfiddle that demonstrates the functionality

http://jsfiddle.net/7pjqfcvd/2/

you have to

1. mark the input element with an Id

   ```
   <input type="text" id="popupMess"/>
   ```
2. use the id in document.getElementById call to obtain the input element

   ```
    var elem = document.getElementById("popupMess");
   ```
3. retrieve the value from the element and pass it into the messagebox

   ```
   window.confirm(elem.value);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

But still if you want to use name then try this...

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Popup</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="popup()">Click for popup</button>
  <input type="text" name=popupMess><br>
  <script>

  function popup() {
     var d = document.getElementsByName("popupMess");
     window.confirm(d[0].value);
  }

 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```